# How do you post to PHP in JavaScript without Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

So I've got this code for a drag and drog file uploader to PHP via ajax, but apparently my web host doesn't have ajax.  Is there any way I can do it without ajax? Specifically I am referring to the UploadFile function, towards the end, after the progress bar parts (which don't seem to work either... )

```
(function() {

// getElementById
function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}


// output information
function Output(msg) {
    var m = $id("messages");
    m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
}


// file drag hover
function FileDragHover(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
}


// file selection
function FileSelectHandler(e) {

    // cancel event and hover styling
    FileDragHover(e);

    // fetch FileList object
    var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

    // process all File objects
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        ParseFile(f);
        UploadFile(f);
    }

}


//upload images
function UploadFile(file) {


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ( xhr.upload && file.type == "image/jpeg" || file.type == "image/gif" || file.type == "image/jpg" || file.type == "image/png" && file.size <= $id("MAX_FILE_SIZE").value
) {

        //create progress bar
        var o = $id("progress");
        var progress = o.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
        progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode("upload " + file.name));


        //progress bar
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
            progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
        }, true);


        //file received/failed
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
            }
        };

        //start upload
        xhr.open("POST", $is("upload").action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", file.type);
        xhr.send(file);

    }



}


// initialize
function Init() {

    var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
        filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
        submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

    // file select
    fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

    // is XHR2 available?
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload) {

        // file drop
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
        filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
        filedrag.style.display = "block";

        // remove submit button
        submitbutton.style.display = "block";
    }

}

// output file information
function ParseFile(file) {

    Output(
        "<p>File information: <strong>" + file.name +
        "</strong> type: <strong>" + file.type +
        "</strong> size: <strong>" + file.size +
        "</strong> bytes</p>"
    );

    // display an image
    if (file.type.indexOf("image") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            Output(
                "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong><br />" +
                '<img src="' + e.target.result + '" /></p>'
            );
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        $("#fileselect").val(file);
    }

    // display text
    if (file.type.indexOf("text") == 0) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            Output(
                "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong></p><pre>" +
                e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") +
                "</pre>"
            );
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

}



// call initialization file
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    Init();
}


})();
```

Comment: AJAX is implemented by you, not supported by your host.  If you've got PHP and JavaScript - and you do - you've got all the tools you need.  You probably have an error in your code.  Consider jQuery, it has great tools to make AJAX easier to implement cross-browser.

Comment: As was said above, AJAX is client-side technology. Your server needs to be able to dish out JSON (which it can using PHP, alternatives include ASP, PERL, etc)... The rest is completely client-side. It simply makes no sense for you to NOT have AJAX, but have PHP.

Comment: @DanRedux: It doesn't have to return JSON, it can return whatever.

Comment: AJAX by definition uses JSON, but AJAX as a technology does also allow for other formats, that's correct. JSON is becoming the de-facto standard, anyway, I struggle to find a popular API which sends you xml by default.

Comment: @DanRedux: By "definition", AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) uses XML. :-P

Comment: Oops. You're right. I had it backwards. Silly me.

Comment: @DanRedux What definition are you using? XML was the defacto standard for AJAX requests for the longest time (using the XMLHttpRequest object)

Comment: What?  Other people have been having problems with ajax on 1and1 too.  http://jonswain.wordpress.com/2007/09/28/ajax-hosting-with-1and1/   And the UploadFile function is failing on if (xhr.upload), which leads me to assume that the issue is with XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @zeiv: If a web host doesn't support `XMLHttpRequest`, they're a crappy web host.  Find a better web host.

Comment: @zeiv What server side technology are you using with 1and1?  I am on 1and1 and use PHP in a Linux environment and have no problems with AJAX (because as others have pointed out, AJAX has nothing to do with the backend).  Are you by any chance relying on .NET extensions for AJAX? 1and1 might not support those, but that doesn't mean AJAX by itself doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A few things first...

---

> my web host doesn't have ajax

This doesn't make much sense. (*or **any** sense to be precise*).

Ajax is just something YOU implement (in Javascript) in order to communicate with the server. (The same way you access a php script on a server; Ajax enables you to "fetch" it, in the background, without the need to reload the page, or being re-directed there).

So, in a few words : It has NOTHING to do with the server/host per se.

**Reference :** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

> Is there any way I can do it without ajax?

**Ajax.**

---

### Examples :

---

- [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [The Ultimate Ajax Object](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Ultimate_Ajax_Object)

Comment: Seems his web host is blocking `XMLHttpRequest` =/

Comment: @Rocket Haven't heard of such a thing... **honestly**! :-/

Comment: @Rocket I doubt 1and1 is blocking the XHR.  I am pretty sure he is relying on some .NET (AJAX) library that 1and1 doesn't have installed.  If the OP decides to not rely on these libraries, I am sure he can get AJAX to work just fine.

Comment: A GET is a GET. A POST is a POST. What about an XHR is different from any other HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

Only modern browsers (read: anything that's not IE) support progress bars on AJAX uploads.  You also need to manage the uploading of files differently in PHP for this to work.

For example: you need to use `fopen("php://input", "r");` instead of `$_FILES`.

Take a look at this AJAX file uploader for more info: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you, use "Iframes" for these kind of situations. i did it 1-2 years ago when we don't want to reload our page for file submission.